# Reducing leading space between vertical-line and second field in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need some help to solve problem in HTML.

I have created vertical line between 2 fields but there is leading space between vertical line and 2nd field. How can I reduce these space and line height according to texts using HTML with CSS?

Here is the code of CSS

```
.row.vertical-divider {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.row.vertical-divider > div[class^="col-"] {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;

}
.row.vertical-divider div[class^="col-"]:first-child {
  border-left: none;

}
.row.vertical-divider div[class^="col-"]:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

Here is the code of HTML

```
<div class="row vertical-divider rightdiv2">
   <div class="col-xs-2">To</div>
   <div class="col-xs-10">Username</div>
 </div>
```

Output is:
[Vertical line between 2 fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85uad.png)

Comment: can you create jsfiddle...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding line-height: 1; to the parent style, like this:

```
.row.vertical-divider {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Also for future reference, examples of what you've tried are really helpful so people know what to avoid trying!

Edit:

Misunderstood your question, sorry there.

I believe the issue is that your text is centering in your col-xs-10. You could try left aligning it, or adding another bootstrap column next to it with a smaller width. See jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rewxz6xu/

Use padding as I have to create space, or like I said, add a new col-xs-? to the right of the Username field.

Comment: Thanks for helping. But what I am asking is there is much leading space between the **line (i.e. line at center)** and the text **Username**. I want reduce that space  : ) Can you help me to solve that?

Comment: Have answered the above in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
.row.vertical-divider {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.row.vertical-divider > div[class^="col-"] {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  //border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
.row.vertical-divider div[class^="col-"]:first-child {
  border-left: none;

}
.row.vertical-divider div[class^="col-"]:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.col-xs-2 {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can simply change the HTML like this (using another class for the second element):

```
<div class="row vertical-divider rightdiv2">
   <div class="col-xs-2">To</div>
   <div class="col-xs-2">Username</div>
 </div>
```